# Python combinations of list of list of lists

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

How do I find combos of a list of lists of lists? Here is an example below.

My list of lists of lists (where the 1st sublist can contain a single list or multiple lists):

```
[[5,6],[[2,4],[5,7]],[1,8],[[-1,-2],[1,0]]]
```

This what I want to get:

```
[5,6],[2,4],[1,8],[-1,-2]    
[5,6],[2,4],[1,8],[1,0]
[5,6],[5,7],[1,8],[-1,-2]
[5,6],[5,7],[1,8],[1,0]
```

Basically looking for the combos for that 2nd level list. I believe it's possible using the `itertools` lib but unsure how to use it.

Comment: `product([[5,6]], [[2,4],[5,7]], [[1, 8]], [[-1,-2],[1,0]])`.

Comment: I'm only looking for the combinations of the 2nd level list, not the "product."

Comment: Did you even try to run that line? Yes, you want a product of the nested lists, your only mistake is not to put the single element lists into a list of their own.

Comment: Try out the code in the first comment. I believe that you will find that it does what you want, at least approximately (using tuple rather than lists). The words `product` and `combination` have technical meanings here, and apparently you really are asking for a Cartesian product, not for combinations.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: I ran `for c in product([[5,6]], [[2,4],[5,7]], [[1, 8]], [[-1,-2],[1,0]]): print(*c)`, that produces the expected output by unpacking the tuple.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It is not possible to answer this question?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I guess the answer is not like only using `product` function from `itertools`.